# This compiles to create a straight horizontal line rather than the cosine plot I was going for

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{TikZ}
\usepackage{PGF}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}



\draw[thick, domain=-3/2:3/2] plot (\x, {cos(\x)});




\end{tikzpicture}




\end{document}
```

there's some extra preamble just so you know what I'm using.

Comment: pst-plot *and* tikz ??  please create a **minimal** compilable example that shows the problem with the fewest possible package in it.  You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: TikZ assumes degrees, not radians, as input to the trigonometric functions.

Comment: do you know if there's a way that the input can be changed to radians or do I have to put change it myself?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the answer given by @Zarko makes sure the input is in radians :)

Comment: See Zarko's answer, or use `{cos(deg(\x))}`. (Note also that only the user who owns the post is notified of all comments. When replying to other comments, write a `@` immediately followed by the username, and that user will be notified. When you start typing a username, a box with the name should pop up, and you can hit the Tab-key to complete it. Only one user per comment can be notified.)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Within the `\begin{tikzpicture}` line you can add `\begin{axis}`. This allows you to either add a plot from coordinates or from an equation. Using

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[
    domain=0:360, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
]
{cos(\x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

for example gives a plot of cosine between `0` and `360`. You can change the range from the `domain` line.

With regards to what you were asking (oops I'm a fool!)  Using

`\draw[thick, domain=-3/2:3/2] plot (\x, {cos(deg (\x))});`

instead makes sure the domain is large enough with the `deg(\x)`

Answer (score 3):

used domain is so small, that the change of `cos(...)` is negligible. try:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{TikZ}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick, domain=-3/2:3/2] plot (\x, {cos(\x r)});% <--- observe added r
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

function `cos` default use argument in degrees. if you like, that it consider radians, you need to add `r` to function arguments is done in *mwe* above.

[image]